# How do I render a standalone component on NUXT 2 which doesn't destroy on route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Usually in vue 2, you render a component that doesn't close on route change, you include it directly in your app.vu file. How do I achieve this in nuxt 2.

I am trying to implement a chat module and don't want to include the component on every instance it is needed (`That will mean new socket connection on every route`)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Include the same component on every page

Comment: From React I know you could do this. I'm fairly sure the same will apply to Vue. Put it on a higher common route, or alternatively, "break it out of the current page"... I think this could be achieved with portals. I see Vue has this https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/portal-a-new-feature-in-vue-3/

Comment: @RohanBüchner no need for a portal here. Put that in your `default` layout, it should be enough. Otherwise, you could indeed have your content nested inside of a main parent wrapper. More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#default-layout

Comment: Thank you very much @kissu this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that in your `default` layout, it should be enough.
More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#default-layout

Something like this in `/layouts/default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink to="/">Home</NuxtLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink to="/parent">Parent</NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <img src="~/assets/logo.svg" />
      <Nuxt />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

And a simple page should do it

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Nuxters! </h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

No need to define a specific layout here since `default` is the one used by default.

Codesandbox example available here: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/nested-pages

---

Otherwise, you could indeed have your content nested inside of a main parent wrapper.